# Random Numbers in C Through a Function (Beginner Programmer)

Tags: c, function, random

I create a simple game to make the user guess a random number from 1 to 10. It worked fine and then I tweaked it to where I made a function that took 2 arguments, a high and low value, to generate a random number. Doing this through the function always returns the value of the highest number entered as an argument when it should return a random number. Here is my code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"

int main(void) {

  int storedNum, low, high, userGuess;

  printf("Welcome to my random numbers game! You will choose a lower number and a maximum number and me, the computer, will choose a random number between those two values for you to guess.\n\nFirst, choose the lowest value");
  scanf("%d", &low);
  printf("Now, choose the highest value");
  scanf("%d", &high);

  storedNum = randomNumbers(low, high);
  printf("We have guessed a number between %d and %d. Guess our number!: ", low, high);
  scanf("%d", &userGuess);

  while (userGuess != storedNum){
    if(userGuess < storedNum){
      printf("higher!: ");
      scanf("%d", &userGuess);
    }
    else{
      printf("Lower!: ");
      scanf("%d", &userGuess);
    }
  }

  printf("You are correct the number was %d!", storedNum);
  return 0;
}

int randomNumbers(int maxNum, int minNum){
  int number;
  srand(time(NULL));
  number = rand()%maxNum + minNum;
  return number;
}
```

The code works fine as long as I generate my random number within the main method, but whenever I use it through a function I always get the same return value. I think the problem lies within the seed being inside the function, but I am not entirely sure. Even if that was the issue I am not sure how I would fix that and get my code working.

Basically, I am trying to write a function that I can reuse in other programs to generate a random number between x and y.

here is some sample output:

```
Welcome to my random numbers game! You will choose a lower number and a maximum number and me, the computer, will choose a random number between those two values for you to guess.

First, choose the lowest value 1
Now, choose the highest value 10
We have guessed a number between 1 and 10. Guess our number!:  5
higher!:  8
higher!:  9
higher!:  10
You are correct the number was 10!
```

No matter what numbers I enter it always returns the max value (in this case 10). Thanks in advance for any and all help and I hope this post finds you well.

Comment: Do not set the random seed in the function. It does not add any extra randombess. Do it once in `main`.

Comment: Probably not the root cause of your problem, but: `randomNumbers(low, high);` --> `randomNumbers(high, low);`. Or swap the param order in the function definition.

Comment: I've tried that and still get the same issue, sorry should have put that in the post as well, will edit. I tried putting the seed just before I call the function, but it still yields same results. Thank you however.

Comment: @kaylum I feel like a complete idiot. Of course it would be something that simple that I overlooked. Thanks so much for youre help this is literally the only thing that was wrong, thanks so much for catching my stupidity.

Comment: This code should generate a warning for a missing prototype. Don't write ancient C!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 rand()%maxNum + minNum;
```

`rand ()` will generate a number between `0` and `RAND_MAX`.

`rand%maxNum` will be a number `<= min(rand(),maxNum-1)`

so the number that you will get is `<=min(rand(),maxNum-1) + minNum` which could exceed `maxNum`

- To get a correct random number between MIN and MAX better to stick to this formula:

  `(rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;`

Comment: Thanks for that formula I was having issues when it came to larger numbers, however, my actual problem lied within me having my parameters in the wrong place when I called the function. Something so simple ha! Thanks so much for that formula though will come in handy!

Answer (score -2):

rand() is quite straight forward

Comment: Right, i'm just trying to figure out why its behavior is not the same inside the main method vs in the function.